# Deprecated: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.scheme is deprecated

Tags: deprecated, url-scheme

I have this Codesnippet:

```
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", factory, 443));
```

It says that the constructor for Scheme is deprecated, but I honestly didn't really understand which new method to use instead.
Can someone show me a brief example on how to use it properly?

the complete Code in which it is used looks like this:

```
        org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory factory = new org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory(clientStore, p12Password, trustStore);
        SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", factory2, 443));

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpParams,schemeRegistry), httpParams);
```

Yes, the "new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpParams,schemeRegistry)" is also deprecated and I may open another Question for it, but it would be good to get started with the Scheme thing, to fix everything step by step.

Regards and thanks for answers
PS: First Question here, I have been a silent reader most of the time, I of course look forward to advices on how to ask questions in the next time, still don't be too harsh please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/scheme/Scheme.html#Scheme%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactory%29), you should use this constructor instead:

```
Scheme(String name, int port, SchemeSocketFactory factory)
```

Comment: Concerning the ThreadSafeClientConnManager: 
I am using ApacheHttpClient 4.1.2. I saw that I should use PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager instead, but this is only supported since 4.2 
So I can ignore Eclipse's warning that the ThreadSafeClientConnManager is deprecated as long as I stay with 4.1.2 or 4.2, right?

Comment: Yes, you can ignore the warning, but I'd also suggest: consider updating to a newer version (4.3), to avoid this kind of problems ;)